# How to add the new module in the qor/admin in golang?

Tags: go

I wanted to add the module to the qor/admin.I installed the qor/admin by using go get command.

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You use `go get github.com/qor/admin` to get the package.

Then you import it with

```
import github.com/qor/admin
```

To see a sample check the github page of [qor/admin](https://github.com/qor/admin)